# Is a result set required to retrieve only single row queries results?

Tags: jdbc

I know only one record fetching form sql query in jdbc example, do I need to use result set interface to store that only one row, or is there any way to store results from single result queries?

Comment: Have you looked at the JDBC API, have you seen any other way? BTW: You don't 'store' the row, you retrieve the row through the result set.

Comment: thanks for responce, i have been recently asked by interviewer that do you require resultset object to retrieve the single result queries, i was confused, i dont know any other way, could you please tell me

Comment: There isn't any other way to retrieve values from a database (at least not in JDBC itself). However as you are talking about storing, are you talking about querying or talking about inserting/updating data?

Comment: the interviwer asked me " if you know only one record will be fetched from the database query , will you use iterator , if yes why? if not why?" could you please help me out